# Get initials of names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have Person and group names

> Person :

```
Robert Smith
David Smith
James Johnson
William
```

if i use this code

```
if(Name.split(",").length === 1)
  return Name.trim().split(" ").map(x => x[0]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr) 
else 
  return ''
```

Output is

1. RS
2. DS
3. JJ

but in my second scenario there are sets of names

like

1. `Robert Smith,David Smith`
2. `James Johnson,Robert Smith`

in this case if any comma is found i want to return `RD` in first case and in second case `JS`

Comment: ....... ok, and?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, I assume you need to get the initial of the first and last name in the first scenario and get the initial of each name in the second scenario.

Check whether the following solution helps,

```js
const scenario1 = "Robert Smith";
const scenario2 = "Robert Smith,David Smith";

function getInitial(data) {

  const chunks = data.split(",");
  
  if ( chunks.length > 1) {
    const initials = [];
    chunks.forEach(chunk => initials.push(chunk[0]));
    return initials.join('');
  } else {
    const [fname, lname] = chunks[0].split(' ');
    return `${fname[0]}${(lname ? lname[0] : '')}`;
  }

}

console.log(getInitial(scenario1))
console.log(getInitial(scenario2))
```